# How to resolve the hostname between the pods in the kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, slurm, kube-dns

I am creating two pods with a custom docker image(ubuntu is the base image). I am trying to ping the pods from their terminal. I am able to reach it using the IP address but not the hostname. How to achieve without manually adding `/etc/hosts` in the pods?

Note: I am not running any services in the node. I am basically trying to setup slurm using this.

Pod Manifest File:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: slurmctld
  labels:
    app: slurm
spec:
  nodeName: docker-desktop
  hostname: slurmctld
  containers:
    - name: slurmctld
      image: slurmcontroller
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6817
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "1000Mi"
          cpu: "1000m"
        limits:
          memory: "1500Mi"
          cpu: "1500m"  
      command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
      args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: worker1
  labels:
    app: slurm
spec:
  nodeName: docker-desktop
  hostname: worker1        
  containers:
    - name: worker1
      image: slurmworker
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6818
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "1000Mi"
          cpu: "1000m"
        limits:
          memory: "1500Mi"
          cpu: "1500m"    
      command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
      args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

Comment: You need a Service matching each Pod.  Usually you wouldn't use bare Pods, but rather a higher-level controller like a Deployment.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods)

> In general a pod has the following DNS resolution:
>
> `pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster-domain.example`.
>
> For example, if a pod in the `default` namespace has the IP address
> `172.17.0.3`, and the domain name for your cluster is `cluster.local`, then the Pod has a DNS name:
>
> `172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local`.
>
> Any pods created by a Deployment or DaemonSet exposed by a Service
> have the following DNS resolution available:
>
> `pod-ip-address.deployment-name.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`

If you don't like to deal with ever changing IP of a pod then you need to create [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to expose the pods using DNS hostnames. Below is an example of service to expose the `slurmctld` pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: slurmctld-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: slurm
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 6817
```

Assuming you are doing these on `default` namespace You should now be able to access it via `slurmctld-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `hostname -i` which in all k8s installs i've tested resolves to the pods IP address.